# Error message: ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, resolution

The error is occuring in this line of my code:

```
df_temp[i] = df_selected['Demand'].loc[mask].values
```

The full error comes up as:

> File "pandas\lib.pyx", line 1544, in pandas.lib.get_blkno_indexers
>   (pandas\lib.c:26770)
>
> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)

Would love to know if anyone knows what this means!

Comment: What are the values for *i* and *mask*?

Comment: i is a column name from within the dataframe - 'MAC002' for example. mask is a Boolean array with 48 true values. The length of the columns in df_temp is 48

Comment: I'm having the same error. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Have you tried `df_temp[i] = df_selected.loc[mask, 'Demand'].values` instead?